# Is there a way to use Relative Path in "Command line arguments" start option in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to use a Relative Path in the "Command line arguments" start option setting in Visual Studio 2017/2019?

The below option does not seem to work:

[image]

*Note:* **/loadmodules** and **/addmodulesfulder** are flags that the start application accepts

If it's not possible to use a relative path as a startup option, is there any alternative ways?

This is the File hierarchy I have at the moment:

```
Root:
    - 10.0.0
    - Build
        - Modules
    - SolutionFolder
```

Comment: What directory do you want it to be relative to? The external program you're starting? The project's directory?

Comment: I added the file hierarchy I am dealing with. Basically, I am trying to pass `dll` files located inside the `Modules` folder in when I ran the project which is located inside the "SolutionFolder"

Comment: That external program you start doesn't know beans about your project.  You'll first have to figure out what default directory it uses.  After which you probably have a wholeheckofalot of `..` to get back to a directory they have in common.  This does get unpractical in a hurry, high odds you should change the project's Output path property so it starts resembling the final install location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the default working directory if you don't specify one is the `bin\Release` (or similar) directory. Set the "Working directory" field to the directory you want your relative paths to be based on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will test if that's going to work tomorrow (don't have access to the project just now)

Comment: I had a chance to test your suggesting. However, I didn't get it to work. I changed my "Working directory" from "path-to-project\Build\bin\AnyCPU\Debug" "path-to-project\Build\" and I set my "Command line arguments" to /loadallmodules /addmodulefolder:".\Modules" but that didn't seem to work. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev Yeah, that's what I suggested. Maybe the app you're running resolves paths differently? If I use `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` as the program and `/c echo %CD%` as the arguments it correctly prints out the working directory I specified when I run without debugging.

Comment: Yeah, it is possible that the app resolves the paths in a different way. I will accept you answer though as it does resolve my question. Thanks